# General slice is invalid on data frame containing Date column?

Tags: r

I create a data frame with Date column as:

```
yrmonday=as.Date(sapply(2000:2017,function(x) {
     seq(as.Date(paste0(as.character(x),'-01-01')),by='8 day',length=46)}),
     origin='1970-01-01')

df <- data.frame(date=yrmonday,
                 fid=rep(1:46,time=18),
                 dayorder=rep(seq(1,365,8),time=18),
                 value=runif(length(yrmonday))
                 )
```

Common operation is not available to this data frame.

```
> tail(df)
Error in `[.default`(xj, i, , drop = FALSE) : subscript out of bounds
> df[1:100,]
Error in `[.default`(xj, i, , drop = FALSE) : subscript out of bounds
> head(df)
        date fid dayorder      value
1 2000-01-01   1        1 0.92817146
2 2000-01-09   2        9 0.59638497
3 2000-01-17   3       17 0.72256721
4 2000-01-25   4       25 0.04086397
5 2000-02-02   5       33 0.01346682
6 2000-02-10   6       41 0.57895922
Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
broken data frame:....
```

I'm confused why it report such error?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of coercing the `Date` class to `integer` and then reconvert it, better option is create it as a `list` and use `do.call` with `c`

```
yrmonday <- do.call(`c`, lapply(2000:2017,function(x) 
     seq(as.Date(paste0(as.character(x),'-01-01')),by='8 day',length=46)) )
str(yrmonday)
#  Date[1:828], format: "2000-01-01" "2000-01-09" "2000-01-17" "2000-01-25" "2000-02-02" "2000-02-10" "2000-02-18" "2000-02-26" ...

dput(head(yrmonday))
structure(c(10957L, 10965L, 10973L, 10981L, 10989L, 10997L), class = "Date")
```

By using the above as a column in `data.frame`

```
df <- data.frame(date=yrmonday,fid=rep(1:46,time=18),
                 dayorder=rep(seq(1,365,8),time=18),
                 value=runif(length(yrmonday))
             )
```

`tail` and `head` works as expected

```
tail(df)
#          date fid dayorder     value
#823 2017-11-17  41      321 0.2477746
#824 2017-11-25  42      329 0.3980863
#825 2017-12-03  43      337 0.1112133
#826 2017-12-11  44      345 0.4216226
#827 2017-12-19  45      353 0.2391892
#828 2017-12-27  46      361 0.8505323


head(df)
#        date fid dayorder     value
#1 2000-01-01   1        1 0.3654198
#2 2000-01-09   2        9 0.4804265
#3 2000-01-17   3       17 0.6757607
#4 2000-01-25   4       25 0.7864473
#5 2000-02-02   5       33 0.8100581
#6 2000-02-10   6       41 0.0786775
```

---

The issue seems to be related to the change in storage mode from `integer` to `numeric` in `sapply` for the `Date` class (from the OP's 'yrmonday')

```
dput(head(yrmonday))
#structure(c(10957, 10965, 10973, 10981, 10989, 10997), class = "Date")
```

---

A similar way to create the `tbl_df` in `tidyverse` would be

```
library(tidyverse)
map(2000:2017, ~ 
    seq(as.Date(paste0(.x, '-01-01')), by = '8 day', length = 46)) %>% 
     reduce(c) %>% 
  data_frame(date = ., fid = rep(1:46, time = 18),
        dayorder = rep(seq(1, 365, 8), time = 18), value = runif(length(.)))
```

Comment: I think the issue is that `as.Date()` was wrapped around a `matrix()` like `as.Date(matrix(...))` I can make something that breaks R like - `mat <- as.Date(matrix(1:12,nrow=4,ncol=3), origin="1970-01-01")` and `dat <- data.frame(
  mat = mat,
  id = letters[1:12]
)`

Comment: So you end up with two objects with 2-dimensions nested awkwardly inside one another.

Comment: @thelatemail I noticed the `sapply` giving a matrix, but then, when we do the `as.Date`, it is a `vector` and something is going on with that step

Comment: Even after as.Date() the "vector" still has dimensions. Take a look with `dim` - I think that's the issue.